# How to play audio from Ubuntu to AirPlay 2 speakers?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, apple

I have an Ubuntu 20.10 and a pair of [KEF LSX](https://eu.kef.com/products/lsx) to which I want to connect using Apple AirPlay 2. I managed to do it using iTunes on Windows 10 and also my iPhone 8, both in the same LAN as my Ubuntu. With Ubuntu I used *PulseAudio Preferences* (*paprefs*) to enable *Make discoverable Apple AirTunes sound devices available locally* (solved the related bug by creating the link `sudo ln -sv '/usr/lib/pulse-15.0+dfsg1' /usr/lib/pulse-15.0`). The speakers are well detected by Ubuntu but when playing anything I get no sound and the below error in logs:

```
Unexpected/Unhandled response: RTSP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Unexpected/Unhandled response: Content-Length: 0
Unexpected/Unhandled response: Server: AirTunes/366.0
Unexpected/Unhandled response: CSeq: 3
```

Why this happens and what should I do to solve it?

```bsh
$pacmd list sinks

2 sink(s) available.
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 45080 /  69% / -9.75 dB,   front-right: 45080 /  69% / -9.75 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 1999.62 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 2000.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 5
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC1220 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC1220 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6001110000 irq 140"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a348"
        device.product.name = "Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-lineout>
  * index: 2
    name: <raop_output.LSX-02869F.local>
    driver: <module-raop-sink.c>
    flags: NETWORK HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL LATENCY 
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 0
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100%,   front-right: 65536 / 100%
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100%
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 1 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 2
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 250.00 ms
    card: 1 <raop_client._192.168.1.252__7000>
    module: 10
    properties:
        device.string = "[192.168.1.252]:7000"
        device.description = "LSX 02869F"
        device.model = "LSX"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    ports:
        network-output: [192.168.1.252]:7000 (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
    active port: <network-output>
```

Comment: 1.5 years later and no one has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4, https://github.com/juhovh/shairplay works.

Clone, build the project then copy the service file:

```
sudo cp -v /home/gigi/compile/shairplay/shairplay.service /etc/systemd/system/ && sudo chown root: /etc/systemd/system/shairplay.service && sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/shairplay.service && sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Make sure to copy airport.key to the root directory:

```
sudo cp -v /home/gigi/compile/shairplay/airport.key /
```

Start the service:

```
sudo systemctl start shairplay
```

I noticed that after starting/restarting my Raspberry Pi the service simply doesn't work; issuing the command `sudo systemctl restart shairplay` solves the problem.